# image rotation with white background

Tags: c#, gdi+, image-rotation

I guess this one is rather simple for those who use GDI more frequently. I have an image that I want to rotate.

Sample image:

[image: before rotation]

After I apply my rotation, it looks like the following:

[image]

Here's the code used:

```
public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float angle)
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        graphics.TranslateTransform((float)bitmap.Width / 2, (float)bitmap.Height / 2);
        graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
        graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)bitmap.Width / 2, -(float)bitmap.Height / 2);
        graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

What I want to get rid of is the part of the image that remains there from before the rotation. Any attempts to use `DrawRectangle` and `Clear` before calling `DrawImage` gave me white images, which makes some kind of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Image bitmap, float angle) {
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
        graphics.TranslateTransform((float)bitmap.Width / 2f, (float)bitmap.Height / 2f);
        graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
        graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)bitmap.Width / 2f, -(float)bitmap.Height / 2f);
        graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, Point.Empty);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, `result` still contains the unrotated image.

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier Please, check my code again - this code draws rotated image into new bitmap. And it works as expected to me.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! You're absolutely right - it works as expected!